# Mail freezes with initial migration after upgrading to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mail.app

I recently upgraded Mac os 10.5.6 to the new 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion).  So far, everything seems to work fine except Mail.app.  When I open the application for the first time, it begins migrating and then freezes. How can I solve this?

Comment: FYI) My old OS was 10.6.8...

Comment: So, its 10.5.6 or 10.6.8?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the three files which name start with *Envelope*, in **~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData** .

Comment: This is a common problem. The directories you need to delete are cache files and it is safe to delete them. However, if I recall, they are in hidden directories, so you need to know how to enable invisible directories and files in the Finder to find them and delete them.